# Shipping table rates with product step

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, shipping-methods

I setted up shipping method with Table Rates using Price vs Destination.

Now i need for products in a specific category shipping price is calculate in the following way:
**shippingprice = shippingrate*(productsnumber/2)**

Example :
NormalProduct 10€
BigProduct 20€
Shipping Cost 10€

NormalProduct 10€
NormalProduct 10€
Shipping Cost 10€

BigProduct 20€
BigProduct 20€
Shipping Cost 10€

NormalProduct 10€
NormalProduct 10€
NormalProduct 10€
Shipping Cost 10€

BigProduct 20€
BigProduct 20€
BigProduct 20€
Shipping Cost 20€

Comment: Do you need this to work for all products or just products from a certain category?

Comment: just products from some specific categories or i can use a product attribut like "big/small"